# How to sort items in ListView by column bound to an Observable Collection?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How to sort items in ListView by column bound to an Observable Collection ?

I've looked all over the place and I can't find anything *easy enough* or *simple* on this.

Comment: Show us what you have tried ...some solutions are not easy or simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SortDescriptions in CollectionViewSource. Here is an example. If you want it dynamically, you need to code around this. but this should give you an idea.

```
    List<Product> products = Client.GetProductList();
    public ICollectionView ProductView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(products);
    ProductView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ObservableCollectionSort.aspx) too complicated?  It just shows how to use a ListCollectionView to provide the data in the correct order, and to perform the sorting.

Comment: Not bad i will give it a try tomorrow. Thanks!